# How do I attach an event to a hidden element in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is an element on the page that is set to display: none in CSS but I want to attach an event to it so that when I make it visible I can click on the element. I keep getting a strange error with it. Thanks for any help you could give me.

Edit:
The strange error is that I can't seem to get the event to attach to the element.

Edit:
I am no longer getting an error but I am not sure why I am not getting the error anymore. In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: will u please post the code or create a fiddle on `jsfiddle.net`

Comment: If you have code that you are working on, it is helpful if you post the code here for us to look at.

Comment: This question says "I have some problem", "the problem is a problem" and "I don't have a problem any more.. why?". It is obviously completely unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<div id="myelement" style="display:none;">My Element</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var el = document.getElementById('myelement');
  el.onclick = function () { alert('Success!'); }
  // condition to make element visible goes here
</script>
```

Of course, some other function is required to make the element visible, and I am not sure how you want that part to work - so I left that part as a TODO.